# Dragging elements to new positions independently using useSprings hook (+useDrag)

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, react-use-gesture

I was expecting each element to be updating independently, according to its latest positioning. However, moving an element after having moved another causes this unwanted behavior.

[image]

```
export function Ingredients({ ingredients }: IngredientsProps) {
  const [springs, api] = useSprings(ingredients.length, () => ({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  }));
  const bind = useDrag(({ args: [originalIndex], offset: [ox, oy] }) => {
    api.start((index) => {
      if (index !== originalIndex) return;

      return {
        x: ox,
        y: oy,
      };
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
      {springs.map(({ x, y }, i) => (
        <Ingredient key={ingredients[i].name} {...bind(i)} style={{ x, y }}>
          <img
            src={ingredients[i].src}
            alt={ingredients[i].name}
            draggable="false"
          ></img>
        </Ingredient>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`from`](https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/options/#from) property to the generic options:

```
export function Ingredients({ ingredients }: IngredientsProps) {
  const [springs, api] = useSprings(ingredients.length, () => ({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  }));
  const bind = useDrag(({ args: [originalIndex], offset: [ox, oy] }) => {
    api.start((index) => {
      if (index !== originalIndex) return;

      return {
        x: ox,
        y: oy,
      };
    });
  },
  {
    from: ({args: [originalIndex]}) => [
        springs[originalIndex].x.get(),
        springs[originalIndex].y.get()
    ],
  });

  return (
    <>
      {springs.map(({ x, y }, i) => (
        <Ingredient key={ingredients[i].name} {...bind(i)} style={{ x, y }}>
          <img
            src={ingredients[i].src}
            alt={ingredients[i].name}
            draggable="false"
          ></img>
        </Ingredient>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```